# NETLOGO: Reading a csv file exported from matlab and store it as a list of lists

Tags: csv, netlogo, nested-lists

I am trying to read a csv file exported from matlab which contains 35040 rows and 5 columns (each element of this file is a number). After that I want to store such file as a list of lists in Netlogo.
The way I am trying to do this is:

```
globals[mylist]

set mylist (csv:from-file "output.csv" )
show mylist
```

This code actually reads the csv file and saves it as a list of lists of the kind:

```
[[a1 a2 a3 a4 a5] [b1 b2 b3 b4 b5]]
```

The problem is that the last element of each nested list, is stored with a series of semicolons at the end. For example in the first nested list the last element should be 0.7980 but it is stored as "0.7980;;;;;;;;;;;" so as a string.
How can I solve it? Is it a problem related with the csv file I am reading or is it a problem with the code I am using? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is with your CSV file and, depending on where it comes from, the best solution might be to fix it at the source.

That being said, you could also process it within NetLogo in a way that gets rid of the semicolons. Here is an example of how you could do this:

```
to demo
  let list-of-lists [[1 2 3 4 "5;;;;"] [6 7 8 9 "10;;;;;"]]
  let new-list-of-lists map [ xs -> map parse xs ] list-of-lists
  print word "Old list: " list-of-lists
  print word "New list: " new-list-of-lists
end

to-report parse [ value ]  
  report ifelse-value (is-string? value and (position ";" value != false)) [
    ; if the value is a string containing a ";", take the string
    ; up to the position of the ";" and try to convert it to a number
    read-from-string substring value 0 position ";" value
  ] [
    ; otherwise, leave the value alone
    value
  ]
end
```

This is not the most robust code in the world, but if your file follows a regular format, it could work. If not, you can always adapt it for your specific case.

Aside from [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map), the key primitives used here are [`position`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#position) and [`read-from-string`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#read-from-string). If you look them up in the dictionary, you should be able to figure out how it works...

Comment: Thanks a lot Nicolas, your solution worked perfectly.